# Вложенный json словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Ошибка в .json файле:

```
[
  {
    "552241153": 
    {"1": {"time": "07.06.2020 22:59:10", "text": "тест", "status": "Not answered"}}, 
    {"2": {"time": "07.06.2020 22:59:14", "text": "Второй тест","status": "Not answered"}}
  }
]
```

Как можно избежать ошибки и сохранить примерно такую структуру словаря?

Comment: Либо значению начинающемуся c `{"2": ` должен соответствовать какой-то ключ (как "552241153" для первого значения), либо оба значения должны быть в списке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы положить в поле `552241153` несколько объектов, необходимо сделать это поле массивом:

```
[
  {
    "552241153": [
      {
        "time": "07.06.2020 22:59:10",
        "text": "тест",
        "status": "Not answered"
      },
      {
        "time": "07.06.2020 22:59:14",
        "text": "Второй тест",
        "status": "Not answered"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```